# asp.net basepage authorization

Tags: asp.net

I want to control every control(button,label) display or invisable on my asp.net page.

can I override OnPreRender in the basepage and in this method can I  access child(the page inherit from the basepage) page's controls .

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish (since I'm asking, no, it's not clear)? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this.Page** is what you are looking for.